# Gitlab default project visibility when creating projects from terminal

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ce

Whenever I start a new project I add it to my Gitlab VCS (on-premise):

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Commit message"
git remote add origin git@git.example.com:foo.git
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

This results in:

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 5.65 KiB | 2.82 MiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: The private project foo was successfully created.
remote:
remote: To configure the remote, run:
...blah blah blah
```

However, this creates a **private** project. I can create projects in the web GUI; this respects the setting that I want new projects to default to **internal** (Admin > Settings > General > Visibility and access controls > Default project visibility).

I was wondering; is it possible to create a project as above, from the terminal, and specify the visibility (any one of private, internal or public)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official docs say's **no**. Project's created from command line always set to Private by default.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project

> If you have access rights to the associated namespace, GitLab will automatically create a new project under that GitLab namespace with its visibility set to Private by default (you can later change it in the [project’s settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html#how-to-change-project-visibility))

You can change project level from UI or using Gitlab API.

Comment: This is correct. The reason is for security. Pushing to create a new project is easy, which also means it can potentially be done accidentally if a user mistypes the Git remote URL. As such, it's safest to create as private and then allow users to change visibility later.

Comment: @DrewBlessing That was already clear from the documentation (though I'm not sure where you got the reason from; is it your own drawn conclusion or do you have a source?). However, I feel that, when I specify, for example, say a `--yesimsuremakeitpublic` argument to the `git push` command your reason goes out the window. There's lots of commands that have a `-y` ("answer yes to all questions") or `-f` ("force") or similar argument to acknowledge you're about to do something 'dangerous' but don't ask questions and continue without intervention. I don't see why git would be an exception?

Comment: I work for GitLab :) That was my recollection. I think your suggestion makes sense, and would be a good addition. Can you create a feature proposal for that, please? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues

Comment: Would you mind giving an overview of doing this via the API? Frankly it seems impossible without jumping through a hundred hoops. Having a simple "-o internal" option on the command line or in my user profile would save me SO much hassle!

Comment: @user1944491 You can use this method https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#edit-project

Comment: Yes, @Tirex, I saw this, but the required parameter project ID is not returned in the data sent to the cmd-line nor available from a git command inside the project folder, so one now needs to go through the hassle of interrogating the server for all the projects and then iterating the list to find a match. In a shell script.