# gitlab: Project visibility of new projects

Tags: gitlab

I created a new gitlab repo like this:

```
git remote add origin <new gitlab repo address>
git push -u origin master
```

Now "Settings / General / Visibility, project features, permissions / Project visibility" is "private".

Since we create a git repo per customer, this will get done often.

Is there a way to change the default for new projects to "internal"?

We run gitlab on-prem.

Comment: How about using GitlabCLI as pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33692685/4636715) with `visibility_level=10`?

Comment: @vahdet it would be less work, if I could change the default once. I guess your solution works, but this need to be done for every new project.

Answer (score 2):

My answer supposes you have a gitlab server on-prem.

Go to `Admin Area` > `Settings` and set `Default project visibility`

[image]

This settings is global for all projects in this gitlab instance.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not work. It works for repos created via web gui, but not from "git push". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57395788/633961